# Scale font size UITextView on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have a `UITextView` added on my `UIView`. It is just to display a string. 
When I add `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to my `UIView`:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer * pinchGR = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
pinchGR.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:pinchGR];
```

Then i handle action for my UIView and scale font size in UITextView

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
CGFloat currentSize = _textView.font.pointSize;
CGFloat toSize = currentSize * recognizer.scale ;
[_textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:toSize]];
recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

And this is my result, my `UITextView` show very bad (opaque)

[image: myIMG]

How can i do it like Snapchat ?

[image: snapchatIMG]

Please give me some ideas.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't clear. What is the problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated font size for textView but the texts still can't see clearly

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)handlePinchWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizerher //UIFont *font = txtqutoes.font;
CGFloat pointSize = font.pointSize;
NSString *fontName = font.fontName;
UIFont *font = textview.font;

pointSize = ((pinchGestureRecognizer.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize;

if (pointSize < 13) pointSize = 13;
if (pointSize > 80) pointSize = 80;

textview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:pointSize];
```

try this !!!...